# Couldn't install sonata admin bundle using composer Symfony6

Tags: php, docker, symfony, composer-php

I am trying to install sonata admin bundle using this command "composer require sonata-project/admin-bundle" but i keep getting this error i don't know what's the problem :

```
./composer.json has been updated
Running composer update sonata-project/admin-bundle
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Root composer.json requires sonata-project/admin-bundle dev-master, found sonata-project/admin-bundle[dev-manual-merge, dev-jord
isala1991-patch-1, dev-4.x-release-4.25.0, 2.0.0, ..., 2.x-dev, 3.0.0, ..., 3.x-dev, 4.0.0-alpha-1, ..., 4.x-dev, 5.x-dev] but it does not match the constraint. Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json and ./composer.lock to their original content.
```

Composer.json :

```
{
    "type": "project",
    "license": "proprietary",
    "minimum-stability": "stable",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "require": {
        "php": ">=8.1",
        "ext-ctype": "*",
        "ext-iconv": "*",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "^2.9",
        "doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle": "^3.2",
        "doctrine/orm": "^2.15",
        "symfony/console": "6.3.*",
        "symfony/dotenv": "6.3.*",
        "symfony/flex": "^2",
        "symfony/framework-bundle": "6.3.*",
        "symfony/runtime": "6.3.*",
        "symfony/yaml": "6.3.*"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "symfony/maker-bundle": "^1.48"
    },
    "config": {
        "allow-plugins": {
            "php-http/discovery": true,
            "symfony/flex": true,
            "symfony/runtime": true
        },
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "src/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "replace": {
        "symfony/polyfill-ctype": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-iconv": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php72": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php73": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php74": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php80": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php81": "*"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "auto-scripts": {
            "cache:clear": "symfony-cmd",
            "assets:install %PUBLIC_DIR%": "symfony-cmd"
        },
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "@auto-scripts"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "@auto-scripts"
        ]
    },
    "conflict": {
        "symfony/symfony": "*"
    },
    "extra": {
        "symfony": {
            "allow-contrib": false,
            "require": "6.3.*"
        }
    }
}
```

I searched this site for a solution to this problem, but none of the closed questions in stackoverflow helped me. Please help me solve the problem

Comment: Which command did you run to require `sonata-project/admin-bundle`? Did you try to use a specific version? It look strange to me that `dev-master` was chosen as the version requirement. And how is this problem related to Docker?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found out to be dependency problem.

1. First install the `jms/serializer`
2. Then install the `sonata-project/admin-bundle`

```bash
# install jms/serializer explicitly

composer require jms/serializer -W 

# install sonata-project/admin-bundle

composer require sonata-project/admin-bundle
```